# Проблема запуском Face Morpher!

Tags: python, python-3.x

Вот на гитхабе репозиторий :

https://github.com/alyssaq/face_morpher

Устоновил все библиотеки все что нужно но при запуске Facemorpher

выдает ошибку:

```
RuntimeError: Unable to open /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/data/shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat
```

Файл скачал и добавил по пути указаному в ошибки :

```
/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/data/shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat'
```

Что делаю не так? подскажите плиз может кто сталкивался с этой проблемой.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
export DLIB_DATA_DIR=*Путь где лежит файл shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat*
```